# Как подключись том postgresql контейнеру?

Tags: postgresql, docker

Использую для запуска контейнера вот это образ [это образ](https://hub.docker.com/r/crunchydata/crunchy-postgres-gis/tags/).
Подключаю к нему том, например при запуске контейнера передаю параметр:

**-v /Users/user/postgres_data:/pgdata**

Но внутри каталога */Users/user/postgres_data* при запуске нового контейнера всегда создается подкаталог с именем, равным хешу конетенра и конечно никаких таблиц с моими данными, которые я добавлял ранее уже нет. Как подключить том, чтобы после завершения работы контейнера и запуска нового все мои таблицы и данные были на месте?

Answer (score 0):

Верно ли указан каталог внутри контейнера?

Когда я запускал постгрес контейнер, прописывал такой путь:

```
- *путь до каталога на хосте*:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata
```

Но я брал [официальный образ](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)